# Singleton injection with parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, injectable

I do want to use the packages **get_it** and **injectable**. They are both wonderful, but I'm facing a issue. Maybe my idea is wrong.

My application has two singletons and I want to use different base urls for different app flavors. So I added a parameter to the singleton constructor with the baseUrl value.

The problem is now, that injectable has only **@factoryParam** as annotation. The name shows the problem. It's not for singletons.

What will be the best practice for that issue? Should I get rid of constructor injection and inject the baseUrl within the singleton like

```
var url = get_it.get<Config>();
```

or is that not the best idea?

Comment: Let me know if you've found the solution, I'm stuck at the same issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achievied in few ways, you can register different strings for different env e.g.

```
@Environment("dev")
@Named("url") // in case if you injecting other strings
String get devUrl...

@Environment("stage")
@Named("url") // in case if you injecting other strings
String get stageUrl...
```

[Update with example]

```
@Environment("dev")
@injectable
class ExampleOne{
final String _url;

ExampleOne(@Named("url") this._url)
}

@Environment("stage")
@injectable
class ExampleTwo{
final String _url;

ExampleTwo(@Named("url") this._url);
}
```

or just one class:

```
@injectable
class Example{
final String _url;
Example(@Named("url") this._url);
}
```

Comment: And how can I use get_it to retrieve the "url"?